# I am getting "The requested resource is not available" 404 error

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

i am developing a web application,but when i am trying to run the welcome.html and click AddActor button then it directs to a form which post the data to a servlet. And when i am trying to run i am getting this error,please help me out

i am working with sts,tomcat 8,maven web app

[image]

and my dir structure is as below

[image]

welcome.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Film Management System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/angular-route.min.js">></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/appConfig.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/appCtrl.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApplication">
        <img src='../static/bg.png' width="1280" height="222"/>

        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <a href="#/AddNewFilm" class="addfilm_buttton button1" ng-click="action.addFilm()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Add film</a>

            <a href="#/ModifyFilm" class="modifyfilm_buttton button1" ng-click="action.modifyFilm()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Modify  Film</a>

            <a href="#/ModifyFilm" class="searchfilm_buttton button1" ng-click="action.searchFilm()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Search Film</a>

            <a href="#/ModifyFilm" class="removefilm_buttton button1" ng-click="action.removeFilm()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Remove Film</a>

            <a href="ViewAllFilms.html" class="viewallfilms_buttton button1" ng-click="action.getAllFilms()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">View All Films</a>

            <a href="#/AddNewActor" class="addactor_buttton button1" ng-click="action.addActor()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Add Actor</a>

            <a href="#/ModifyActor" class="modifyactor_buttton button1" ng-click="action.modifyActor()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Modify Actor</a>

            <a href="#/SearchActor" class="searchactor_buttton button1" ng-click="action.searchActor()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Search Actor</a>

            <a href="#/RemoveActor" class="removeactor_buttton button1" ng-click="action.removeActor()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Remove Actor</a>

            <a href="ViewAllActors.html" class="viewallactors_buttton button1" onclick="return submitMyForm();" ng-click="action.getAllActors()" ng-hide="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">View All Actors</a>

            <a href="#/" class="show_buttton button1"  ng-click="showButtons()" ng-show="action.buttonClicked.addFilm || action.buttonClicked.modifyFilm || action.buttonClicked.searchFilm || action.buttonClicked.removeFilm  || action.buttonClicked.getAllFilms || action.buttonClicked.addActor || action.buttonClicked.modifyActor || action.buttonClicked.searchActor || action.buttonClicked.removeActor  || action.buttonClicked.getAllActors">Home</a>

        <div ng-view></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my AddNewActor.html is

```
<div id="login">

        <h2><span class="fontawesome"></span>Add New Actor</h2>

        <form action="AddNewActor" method="post">

            <fieldset>

                <p><label for="firstName">Enter Actor First Name</label></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="firstName" value="first name" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='first name'" onFocus="if(this.value=='first name')this.value=''"></p> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="mail@address.com" -->

                <p><label for="secondName">Enter Actor last Name</label></p>
                <p><input type="text" name="lastName" value="last name" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='last name'" onFocus="if(this.value=='last name')this.value=''"></p> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="password" -->

                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
</div>
```

and my web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Film Management System</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>ViewAllActors</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ViewAllActors</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.flp.fms.controller.ViewAllActors</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>ViewALLFilms</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ViewALLFilms</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.flp.fms.controller.ViewALLFilms</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>AddNewActor</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddNewActor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.flp.fms.controller.AddNewActor</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewAllActors</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewAllActors</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewALLFilms</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewALLFilms</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddNewActor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddNewActor</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my AddNewActor.java(servlet)

```
package com.flp.fms.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class AddNewActor extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("tdctdt");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of the wrong servlet path.
Since in your web.xml, there is a mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AddNewActor</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/AddNewActor</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet `AddNewActor` will be invoked when you call to `angularjs_webapp/AddNewActor`, instead of `angularjs_webapp/htmlTemplates/AddNewActor`

You can fix it by making changes in your form action `AddNewActor.html`, to direct a call to its parent directory:

```
<form action="AddNewActor" method="post">
```

should be changed to

```
<form action="../AddNewActor" method="post">
```